# How to hide the application?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application that will run in the device but it will not be visible in "Application Manager". means I don't want any user to see that particular application is running in his device.
How can I do that??

Comment: I'm hoping this isn't possible. Seems like a security risk to me. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: i think i can do this if once i get the root directory .. then i can run that app as a default app of device. but how can i get that root path

Comment: The "root directory" wouldn't be hidden. You can't just run an app with root permissions just because you get the root directory. They are very different things.

Comment: then if there is any other way so plz tell me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Sounds like you are trying to design your app like plugin,

For the above use the following link could have everything to match your expectations,

[Background running application service](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/06/plugins.html)

Anyway if you are having activity and you dont want to show it,

then you can remove the

```
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

from the android manifest under activity category tag.

But removing launcher category will not shows your app in the application list only.

It cannot remove it from application manager. So anyone can see your app in the Settings-Applications-Manage Applications.

Untill unless it needs to be a indeed process to hide from UI please follow the things.

basically hiding an app from user doesn't make sense that much.

Enjoy coding...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to hide the application from Application Manager. You can hide the UI of the App, and the icon which appears on the home screen of the Applications.

for this you can remove the Launcher intent filter from the manifest.xml from the activity.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Remove the Launcher from the category. the app will not appear in the Application Window.

Comment: Thank you Vikash for ur kind help... but i have already completed that part.. now i want to remove this app from Application manager too.

Comment: Hi Devraj, It is not possible to hide the app from Application Manager. Application manager will show all the Apps which runs even the services also.

Comment: Hello Vikas, yes that I can understand that app will display in APP MANAGER.. but i think I can do this. I'll take 3-4 more days to complete this task. I have some ideas regarding this. let's see. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Apps that try to conceal their behavior are usually considered as malware, spyware and spamware and no user will appreciate this. Please drop this idea.

Comment: I think I have read this answer somewhere else too.. and I blv that nothing is impossible.

Comment: admirable sentiment. But all that is possible shouldn't always be done. Trying to hide an app from the user and the system is a very bad idea. Trust me on this.

Comment: @devrajsingh ok if anything is impossible than why do't you tried for it